# How Do I Add A Custom Attribute To The Process Table In Linux?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, attributes, kernel

I am tasked with using a syscall to modify a custom attribute assigned to a process. I understand how to define the syscall and functions to call it and all of the necessary places to update for the syscall addition. However, I cannot find any good information on the location or method to add the custom attribute. From what I can tell, the processes will show up in /proc and I can see their attributes from there. I know about the fork() and do_fork() functions, but I'm not sure if this is where those attributes will be defined. Trial and error has gotten me no where, unfortunately.

Note: This is for a school assignment, so I'd appreciate some hints(things to grep, etc.) and am not looking for a direct answer.

Edit: I see /include/linux/sched.h has some definitions that look promising. Perhaps I need to add it in here somewhere...

Comment: The actual syscall to create a process is `clone`

Comment: @stark What's the difference between clone() and fork()?

Comment: `fork` is a special case which duplicates the current process.  `clone` is the general call to create a new process, possibly with different attributes.